# Touchable Handler behind ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I want to make some sort of Scrollable Paralax effect, in which a ScrollView is set to flex: 1, and behind it there is a absolute positioned element that has some buttons. The ScrollView has a view which acts as the padding to make the absolute view visible. When Scrolling the rest of the content os the ScrollView goes over the absolute view as desirade. The problem is that the absolute view does not respond to touch events, since it is covered by the ScrollView. What solution do I have for this?

This is the code I have now:

```
<View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.static, { backgroundColor: "yellow" }]}
          onLayout={this.onLayout}
        >
          <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} name={name} />
          <Balance balance={balance} />
          <BotonesAccion navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          style={styles.container}
          onScroll={Animated.event([
            { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.y } } }
          ])}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              height: this.state.height,
              backgroundColor: "green",
              opacity: 0.2
            }}
          />
          <Historial navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  static: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    width,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight + theme.sizes.padding,
    padding: theme.sizes.padding
  },
});
```

I want to then use the nativeEvent of the ScrollView to drive some animations, but that is not part of the problem.

Comment: Hi Matias, did you manage to get this working? :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use pointerEvents="box-none" (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents) as a prop for ScrollView

```
<Animated.ScrollView
          pointerEvents="box-none"
          style={styles.container}
          onScroll={Animated.event([
            { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.y } } }
          ])}
        >
<View>
[...]
</View>
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Comment: That is not working :(. Still having the same problem.

Comment: can you provide snack link for this?